# StickyJS - Two sticky elements, how to change the width of only one "stuck" div

Tags: javascript, jquery, sticky

I have a tumblr theme (the code is pure css, html and js, no tumblr elements) and I have a navigation bar (green) and a shop icon (black). I want them both to stick to the top of the page while scrolling, but I want the shop icon to change it's height to match the height of the navigation bar while it's stuck.

The navigation bar works fine now, but again, I want to change the width of shop icon. Also, when the shop icon is stuck, it moves more towards the left and slightly changes the width, but even when I don't add any stlyes, it still does this.

The script I'm using is from stickyjs.com

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/zvesamf/5veoajatd/jquery.sticky.js"></script>
<script>
    $(window).load(function(){
      $(".navigation").sticky({ topSpacing: 0 });
      $(".shop").sticky({ topSpacing: 0, className: '.sticky' });
    });
  </script>
```

The hmtl is

```
<div class="navigation">
    <div class="navigationwrap">
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <a href="#">link</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="shop">

</div>
```

and the css is

```
.navigation {
    float:left;
    width:840px;
    height:42px;
    background:green;
    text-align:center;
}

.navigation.sticky {

    max-width:900px;
    width:900px;
}


.shop {
    float:right;
    margin-top:-58px;
    margin-left:-50px;
    width:226px;
    height:207px;
    background:black;
}

.shop.sticky {
    float:right;
    margin-top:-58px;
    margin-left:-50px;
    width:226px;
    height:42px;
    background:white;
}
```

The github with options are here
https://github.com/garand/sticky

I've tried the default variables, but it changes the navigation bar dimensions instead of the shop icon.

Answer (score 0):

There are events to do it named as `sticky-start` and `sticky-end`. It may not the best way, however, this will do the trick in this case.

```
$('.shop').on('sticky-start', function() { $(this).addClass('sticky') });
$('.shop').on('sticky-end', function() { $(this).removeClass('sticky') });
```

Comment: It actually did work! Thanks. I had to add some more css to work around it jumping while scrolling, but your input fixed it.